# How to assign keys and values in a directory by using python

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to map Illumina pair-end reads against a reference genome. I have a directory in which I only need to use the files that end with paired_R1.fastq.gz and paired_R2.fastq.gz for the paired reads.

I am creating a script in which the paired_R1 are the keys and the paired_R2 are the values; however, I am having difficulties in assigning the keys and values in a for loop. I understand the file1 and file2 are not defined but I don't know how to set the output of "endswith" to a key and value respectively.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    path = os.getcwd()
    dir_files = os.listdir(path)
    pair_reads = {}
    for file in dir_files:
        if file.endswith("_paired_R1.fastq.gz"):
            file = file1
            if file.endswith("_paired_R2.fastq.gz"):
                file = file2
                pair_reads[file1] = file2
    print(pair_reads)
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: can you provide some sample data, i.e a list of file names and then the expected output when said file names are the input

Comment: Can you give an example of a few filenames and how you would expect them to be paired?

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me, but the code worked thanks to Seb, the comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see what logic you were going for. There were just a few issues:

- `file = file1`, which should have been `file1 = file` (same for file2)
- The two conditional statements contradict each other so they should be at the same indentation or one will never be executed
- `dir_files` needs to be sorted for the right files to be associated so `sorted(dir_files)` ensures that.

```py
if __name__=='__main__':
    path = os.getcwd()
    dir_files = os.listdir(path)
    pair_reads = {}
    for file in sorted(dir_files):
        if file.endswith("_paired_R1.fastq.gz"):
            file1 = file
        if file.endswith("_paired_R2.fastq.gz"):
            file2 = file
            pair_reads[file1] = file2 
    print(pair_reads)
```

As long as the directory structure satisfies that there is exactly one `R1` and one `R2` file for each read, this should work fine.

**Edit:** Another way, using list comprehensions:

```py
if __name__=='__main__':
    path = os.getcwd()
    dir_files = sorted(os.listdir(path))
    R1s = [f for f in dir_files if f.endswith("_paired_R1.fastq.gz")]
    R2s = [f for f in dir_files if f.endswith("_paired_R2.fastq.gz")]
    pair_reads = dict(zip(R1s, R2s))
    print(pair_reads)
```